# Can we add the permission to access the table?

Tags: smart-contract, permissions, eosio-code, table

I know how to declare ,initialize and get,set values in a table .My question is Can we add permission to access the table to a particular user  inside our smart contract ?

Comment: tables are open to read for anyone without even needing a blockchain account. i think the closest you can do is encrypt data in a table with someone's public key so they can read it only if they have the secret key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **can not forbid reading** the data from a smart contracts table, because it is exposed by the RPC interface or CLI.

What you can do to **prevent** understanding it by 3rd parties, is **encrypt** your data like @confused00 said.

If you just want to limit access for **adding, modyfing or deleting**, you can use the scopes of the multi_index and the require_auth method, which will check for the right signatures. This would look something like this:

```
require_auth(user);
testIndex1 test1(_self, user); // code, scope
// iterate over first index 
for(auto itr = test1.begin(); itr != test1.end() && count!=pLimit;) {
   // delete element and update iterator reference
   itr = test1.erase(itr);
   count++;
}
```