# Storing encrypted data on EOS blockchain

Tags: eosio-code

The following qa suggests that private data on the blockchain can be stored in an encrypted form:

[Can we add the permission to access the table?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2149/can-we-add-the-permission-to-access-the-table/2150#2150)

My question is whether there are any existing patterns for storing, encrypting, decrypting data to / from EOS blockchain respectively?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All encryption/decryption action must happen offchain and you are free to load any binary data to a chain. Maybe if you can tell more background information about your use case and then people can help you to the right direction?

Comment: The use case example is as follows: within a financial system you have regulators, and banks. While regulator will have to have access to ALL data, individual banks will only have access to subsets of data that they are authorized to view. And wider public will have to have no way to view such data unless authorized. In essence, this is tiered / permissioned access to encrypted data.

Comment: https://medium.com/@pfh/kimono-trustless-secret-sharing-using-time-locks-on-ethereum-8e7e696494d time-lock encryption might be interesting for you

Comment: I would the simplest thing to do is not trying to put this data in to a public chain or blockchain at all. A public blockchain is good for a public data only and in your scenario blockchain does not seem to give any advantage. If you want to have a distributed database across banking partners and regulators e.g. BigChainDb is a better choice. https://www.bigchaindb.com/

Comment: Here are some scenarios for permissions with BigChainDb https://docs.bigchaindb.com/en/latest/private-data.html